# How to find bits of physical address and virtual address?

Tags: operating-system

A system has 512MB physical memory and 4GB virtual memory with a page size of
8KB. (Sznarks)

1. Find the number of bits for the physical address and the virtual address.
2. Find the number of pages and the number of frames.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Find the number of bits for the physical address and the virtual address.

The physical address space needs to be large enough for more than just RAM (you need space for ROM and memory mapped devices; and often there's "unused" space for future expansion). There isn't enough information to say anything other than "physical addresses probably have more than 29 bits", but in that case it's likely that the hardware designer would round it up to a nice "power of 2", so 32 bits is the most likely for number of bits in a physical address.

Virtual addresses would have 32 bits (because "log2(4 GiB) == 32").

> 2. Find the number of pages and the number of frames.

"512 MiB / 8 KiB" works out to 65536 physical pages of RAM alone (excluding ROM, memory mapped devices, etc).

"4 GiB / 8 KiB" works out to a maximum of 524288 virtual pages per virtual address space.